# Is the solution to this (simple) Stochastic Differential Equation unique?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

The SDE is $dX_t=4X_t^{\frac{3}{4}}dB_t+6X_t^{\frac{1}{2}}dt,\ X_0=0$.

The solution obviously is $X_t=B_t^4$.

However is it the unique (strong) solution for this SDE?

I mean if it is true that there are no $X_t'$ such that it satisfies the SDE and $P(X_t=X_t'\ \forall t\geq 0)=1$.

Surely the Lipschitz condidions doesn't hold here, so the uniquness and existence theorem can't be used...

Comment: If you stop the solution $B_t$ at some moment it hits zero, this would be a solution too, so no, there is no uniqueness.

Comment: @zhoraster Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not unique.

Define $\tau_1 = \inf\{t\ge 0: B_t=1\}$, $\tau_0 = \inf\{t\ge \tau_1: B_t = 0\}$. Then $X_t' = B^4_{t\wedge \tau_0}$ is another strong solution.